# Trying to create separate instance of DataSet, but I can't separate them

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataSet called Apples. I need to massage the data table in there so that I can add blank row and a couple other rows. These rows need to be added because I am binding to a ComboBox.

I do not want to add these as rows to my actual DataSet, so I want to create a copy of it and bind my ComboBox to the copy. Problem is, whenever I try and create a copy it's like it's a reference and anything I add to the "copy" ends up in the original.

Here is my syntax, is there any way to get a true separate object? Thanks!

```
Apples.Apple apples = new Apples.Apple();
apples.ReadXml("C:\apples.xml");

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = apples.Apple;
```

Now if I add rows to 'dt', they also show up in "apples.Apple! How can I get around that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `dt = apples.Apple.Copy();`, assuming `Apple` is a DataTable.

Edit: [Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy.aspx), not clone.